# How i use AsyncTask to populate an ListView with Adapter consuming WebService?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-bitmap, listview-adapter

i'm developing a project to complete my technical course in Android-java. In my application I have a part where it consumes the WebService an ArrayList which lists all database Users with an image using a ArrayAdapter. The problem is that I am not able to use this ArrayAdapter and populates the list using AsyncTask, studying on the Internet i am having a bit of trouble to learn how it really works this function. If it were possible i would like to help me to make that call and how to populate the ListView with an Adapter using the Async task . Below will parts of my code:

frmListarEstudios.class

```
public class frmListarEstudios extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listEstudio;
private List<Estudio> ests;
private EstudioDAO dao;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_estudios);

    dao = new EstudioDAO();
    ests = dao.buscarTodosEstudios();
    listEstudio = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEstudios);
    EstudioAdapter estAdp = new EstudioAdapter(this, ests);
    listEstudio.setAdapter(estAdp);
}
```

Here are my Adapter.class and some ridiculous unsuccessfully trys:

```
public class EstudioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<Estudio> ests;
private Context context;

public EstudioAdapter(Context context, List<Estudio> ests){
    this.ests = ests;
    this.context = context;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ests.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return ests.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return ests.get(arg0).getID_ESTUDIO();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lista_estudios, parent, false);

    ImageView imgLogoEstudio = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgLogoEstudio);
    TextView txtNomeEstudio = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeEstudio);
    TextView txtCidadeEstudio = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtCidadeEstudio);
    TextView txtSiteEstudio = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtSiteEstudio);
    TextView txtFoneEstudio = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtFoneEstudio);

    Estudio estudioDaVez = ests.get(position);


    txtNomeEstudio.setText(estudioDaVez.getNOME_FANTASIA_ESTUDIO());
    txtCidadeEstudio.setText(estudioDaVez.getCIDADE_ESTUDIO() + "-" + estudioDaVez.getESTADO_ESTUDIO());
    txtSiteEstudio.setText(estudioDaVez.getSITE_ESTUDIO());
    txtFoneEstudio.setText(estudioDaVez.getTELEFONE_ESTUDIO());

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(estudioDaVez.getLOGO_ESTUDIO(), 0, estudioDaVez.getLOGO_ESTUDIO().length);
    imgLogoEstudio.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    chamarPegarImagem(estudioDaVez);
    return rootView;
}

private void chamarPegarImagem(Estudio position){
    pegarImagem imagem = new pegarImagem();
    Log.i("AsyncTask", "AsyncTask senado chamado Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    imagem.execute(position);
}



private class pegarImagem extends AsyncTask<Estudio, Void, Bitmap> {
    private View view;
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Estudio... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(params[0].getLOGO_ESTUDIO(), 0, params[0].getLOGO_ESTUDIO().length);
        Log.d("merda", String.valueOf(bitmap));

        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
        if(bitmap!=null) {

            //getView(imgLogoEstudio.setImageBitmap(bitmap));
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "Exibindo Bitmap Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }else{
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "Erro ao baixar a imagem " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "Tirando ProgressDialog da tela Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

And here are my DAO Object:

```
public class EstudioDAO {

private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.2:8080/photoprintws/services/EstudioDAO?wsdl";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.photoprint.com.br";


private static final String BUSCAR_TODOS = "buscarTodosEstudios";


public List<Estudio> buscarTodosEstudios() {

    List<Estudio> listaEst = new ArrayList<Estudio>();

    SoapObject buscarEstudios = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, BUSCAR_TODOS);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarEstudios);

    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        //USAR ISSO ABAIXO PARA EVITAR QUE O KSOAP NÃO FAÇA CONEXÃO E RETORNE VALOR NULO
        //ISSO VAI EVITAR CRASH NO APP!

        ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerPropertyArrayList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
        headerPropertyArrayList.add(new HeaderProperty("Connection", "close"));

        http.call("urn:" + BUSCAR_TODOS, envelope, headerPropertyArrayList);

        if (envelope.getResponse() instanceof SoapObject) {
            SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            Estudio est = new Estudio();

            est.setID_ESTUDIO(Integer.parseInt(resposta.getProperty("ID_ESTUDIO").toString()));
            est.setRAZAO_SOCIAL_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("RAZAO_SOCIAL_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setNOME_FANTASIA_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("NOME_FANTASIA_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setCNPJ_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("CNPJ_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setSENHA_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("SENHA_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setESTADO_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("ESTADO_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setCIDADE_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("CIDADE_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setBAIRRO_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("BAIRRO_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setRUA_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("RUA_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setCEP_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("CEP_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setCOMPLEMENTO_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("COMPLEMENTO_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setTELEFONE_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("TELEFONE_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setEMAIL_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("EMAIL_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setSITE_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("SITE_ESTUDIO").toString());
            est.setSALDO_ESTUDIO(Float.parseFloat(resposta.getProperty("SALDO_ESTUDIO").toString()));
            est.setSALDO_PENDENTE_ESTUDIO(Float.parseFloat(resposta.getProperty("SALDO_PENDENTE_ESTUDIO").toString()));
            est.setSALDO_BLOQUEADO_ESTUDIO(Float.parseFloat(resposta.getProperty("SALDO_BLOQUEADO_ESTUDIO").toString()));
            est.setSTATUS_ESTUDIO(Integer.parseInt(resposta.getProperty("STATUS_ESTUDIO").toString()));

            String logoEstudio = resposta.getProperty("LOGO_ESTUDIO").toString();

            byte[] bt = Base64.decode(logoEstudio, Base64.DEFAULT);
            est.setLOGO_ESTUDIO(bt);

            listaEst.add(est);
        } else {
            Vector<SoapObject> retorno = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();

            for (SoapObject resposta : retorno) {

                Estudio est = new Estudio();

                est.setID_ESTUDIO(Integer.parseInt(resposta.getProperty("ID_ESTUDIO").toString()));
                est.setRAZAO_SOCIAL_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("RAZAO_SOCIAL_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setNOME_FANTASIA_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("NOME_FANTASIA_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setCNPJ_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("CNPJ_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setSENHA_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("SENHA_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setESTADO_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("ESTADO_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setCIDADE_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("CIDADE_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setBAIRRO_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("BAIRRO_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setRUA_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("RUA_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setCEP_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("CEP_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setCOMPLEMENTO_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("COMPLEMENTO_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setTELEFONE_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("TELEFONE_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setEMAIL_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("EMAIL_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setSITE_ESTUDIO(resposta.getProperty("SITE_ESTUDIO").toString());
                est.setSALDO_ESTUDIO(Float.parseFloat(resposta.getProperty("SALDO_ESTUDIO").toString()));
                est.setSALDO_PENDENTE_ESTUDIO(Float.parseFloat(resposta.getProperty("SALDO_PENDENTE_ESTUDIO").toString()));
                est.setSALDO_BLOQUEADO_ESTUDIO(Float.parseFloat(resposta.getProperty("SALDO_BLOQUEADO_ESTUDIO").toString()));
                est.setSTATUS_ESTUDIO(Integer.parseInt(resposta.getProperty("STATUS_ESTUDIO").toString()));

                String logoEstudio = resposta.getProperty("LOGO_ESTUDIO").toString();

                byte[] bt = Base64.decode(logoEstudio, Base64.DEFAULT);
                est.setLOGO_ESTUDIO(bt);

                listaEst.add(est);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return listaEst;
}
```

Comment: What data are you return from your web service? Json or Xml?

Comment: i'm using XML return @Eenvincible

Comment: Can you help me with this issue @Eenvincible ?